# Cardinality of sets ($\aleph_0$, distinct elements)

Tags: cardinals

Which answers are correct?

- $| \{1000, 1001 \}| = 2$: True.
- $| \{1, 2, 2, 3 \}| = 4$: False. There are only $3$ distinct elements.
- The cardinality of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is $\aleph_0$: I'd say true since each element is -- distinct and countable -- though the counting may go on forever.

Comment: Your justification for 5.c is sort of unclear (the other two look fine). It's possible to have uncountable sets where every element is countable.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by platty, apart from 5.c all are fine.

5.c: The anwer is correct, but reasoning is vague.

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined by: $f((i,j)) = \frac{(i+j+1)(i+j-2)}{2} + j$. Then you can show that $f$ is a bijection (this map is called **Cantor's diagonalization map**.) And since $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same cardinality, we are done.